# Calc $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty -\frac{t}{1+t^2}(\delta (\omega-t-\pi)-\delta(\omega-t+\pi))dt$

Tags: fourier-series, convolution

The answer to this integral:$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty -\frac{t}{1+t^2}(\delta (\omega-t-\pi)-\delta(\omega-t+\pi))dt$$

is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(-\frac{\omega-\pi}{1+(\omega-\pi)^2}+\frac{\omega+\pi}{1+(\omega+\pi)^2}\right)$$
It came from a Fourier transform convolution integral.

I have no idea how to compute it. Help?

Comment: There's not much to compute. Recall the definition of $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)\delta(a-t)\,dt$$ (and ignore that the notation doesn't strictly make sense).

Comment: You already did it. It makes sense.

Answer (score -4):

Hint: remember that 
$$ \delta(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
1&\text{ if }x=0,\\
0&\text{ else.}
\end{array}\right. $$

Comment: That would mean $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta (x) dx = 0$....

Comment: @xpaul: I know that $f(t)\cdot \delta(t-a)=f(a)$ but what about the case $f(t)\cdot \delta(a-t)$?

Comment: @UdiBehar You get the same thing: $\int f(t) \delta(a-t)=f(a)$ (provided the domain of integration has $a$ in its interior). You can check this by changing variables to $a-t$ to reduce to the more typical form.

Comment: @Ian thank a lot! I got the thrill now. :)

Comment: It means $\delta\left(\,x\,\right)=2\delta\left(\,x\,\right)\ \Longrightarrow\ 1 = 2$ !!!.

Comment: Life would be a bit boring with at most one unique number in existence, and even more because it's $0$...

Comment: Why downvoted the hint? In Fourier Analysis, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\delta(t-a)dt=f(a)$.

Comment: @FelixMarin, it is not true since $\delta(x)\neq 2\delta(x)$.

Comment: @Dor, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)dx=1$.

Comment: @xpaul you don't say...! (In fact this is *the* definition, along with $\delta (x) = 0$ for any $x \neq 0$). But, try to integrate $\delta$ using your definition man!

Comment: @Dror, I just gave a hint.

Comment: @xpaul I know it's not true. "If we follow the OP definition" we'll get that conclusion. I don't remember clearly but I believe this example is from the Schwartz book.

Comment: There is a nice introduction [over here](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/ivan.wilde/notes/gf/gf.pdf) which, I believe so, provides a good start for mathematicians.

Comment: @xpaul, just to clear up confusion, I think you meant to say that at $x=0$, $\delta(x) = \infty$. Of course, that's not enough for the definition. You have to say that's it's equal to infinity _such that_ when you integrate over it, the integral is 1. Remember, the bin of the region where $\delta(x)$ is not zero has width zero, not a non-negligible width, so integrating over _your_ definition would simply return 0 (the $x=0$ contribution would be negligible.)